# Socks proxy on mac's shared internet

Tags: macos, internet, ipod-touch

I use my mac's internet sharing to create wireless network for my ipod touch. I have a linux server and I use socks proxy. I wanna use this proxy on my ipod but i don't know how. I put my shared network connection behind the proxy with localhost ip but my ipod isn't behind the proxy. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a proxy in the advanced properties of your Wi-Fi connection on the iPod. In the Wi-Fi selection tap the arrow-button next to your Wi-Fi network and scroll to the bottom to set up the proxy.

Comment: what ip and port should I put there?

Comment: the one of your proxy. Sorry, this configuration is different for each proxy, so I can't really help you.